# Karaoke application for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-recommendation, music

Are there any karaoke application available for Ubuntu 16.04? I have found only PyKaraoke.

Comment: this is opinion-based

Comment: @MarkYisri I disagree :)

Comment: If you have specific features that you require you might ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ if your just looking for general info see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The software center is pretty good at finding available packages. See below:

[image: karoke]

As you can see, there are several related packages that come up. Performous being the top hit.  I believe the others are aimed toward creation of karaoke effects.You can install and try any or all of these to determine which of these (or combination thereof) best fits your requirements.

Comment: Performous does not appear to handle standard karaoke formats (mp4, or mp3+cdg).  Silverjuke does seem to "just work" with mp3+cdg.

Comment: @phs If you are still using 16.04 You should strongly consider upgrading to a more recent version as Hardware and maintenance updates have now or will soon cease.